# Can someone explain the issue that is happening on my WordPress theme website?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

When the domain name *frameless.ca* is called, the website loads for a millisecond and then the page turns blank, after another second or two, the whole site loads again.

I need to find out what is causing this delay. Since its a theme based site, the code is hard to go through. I was wondering if someone on here is expert enough to figure out the issue and isolate it?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Either your theme or some plugin is generating following CSS code that is responsible for this ***page load > blank page > page load*** cycle:

```
<style type="text/css"title="dynamic-css"class="options-output">
    body {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading body {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading body {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .heading .title {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .heading .title {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .heading .title {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .heading .subtitle {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .heading .subtitle {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .heading .subtitle {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .navigation-top .menu a,
    .navbar-default .navigation-top .menu>li>a {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .navigation-top .menu a,
    .wf-loading .navbar-default .navigation-top .menu>li>a {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .navigation-top .menu a,
    .ie.wf-loading .navbar-default .navigation-top .menu>li>a {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .btn-primary,
    .btn-inverse:hover,
    #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type="submit"],
    .ctct-embed-signup .ctct-button,
    .contact input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #2b6560;
    }
    .btn-primary,
    .btn-inverse,
    #mc-embedded-subscribe-form input[type="submit"],
    .ctct-embed-signup .ctct-button {
        border-color: #2b6560;
    }
    .btn-inverse {
        color: #2b6560;
    }
    .navigation-top .menu>li.active a,
    .navigation-top .menu>li>a:hover {
        border-color: #31ddb7;
    }
    a,
    a:hover,
    a:focus,
    .testimonials blockquote p:before,
    .pagemeta a:link,
    .pagemeta a:visited {
        color: #31ddb7;
    }
    .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
    .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,
    .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
    .heading .title span,
    .main-navigation li li:hover,
    .main-navigation li li.focus {
        background-color: #31ddb7;
    }
    .navbar-default {
        background-color: #2b6560;
    }
    .navbar .navigation-top {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    .navbar-transparent .site-title a {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .navbar-transparent .site-title a {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .navbar-transparent .site-title a {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .navbar-default .site-title a {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .navbar-default .site-title a {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .navbar-default .site-title a {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .hero h1 {
        font-family: Montserrat;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: 1.25px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 49px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .hero h1 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .hero h1 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .hero h2 {
        font-family: Bayon;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: 1.25px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #dbdbdb;
        font-size: 35px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .hero h2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .hero h2 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .hero {
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url('https://frameless.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Twilight-1-1.jpg');
    }
    #welcome {
        padding-top: 250px;
        padding-bottom: 200px;
    }
    .features .feature i {
        color: #19232d;
        font-size: 50px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .features .feature i {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .features .feature i {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .features .feature h3 {
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 1.25px;
        color: #19232d;
        font-size: 30px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .features .feature h3 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .features .feature h3 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .features {
        background-color: #a8ffef;
    }
    .features {
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 130px;
    }
    .work {
        background-color: #2b6560;
    }
    #work {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .gallery {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .gallery {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .project-single {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .project-single {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .projects-grid {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .projects-grid {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .clients {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .clients {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .stats .fa,
    .stats p {
        color: #ffffff;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .stats .fa,
    .wf-loading .stats p {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .stats .fa,
    .ie.wf-loading .stats p {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .stats {
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url('https://frameless.ca/wp-content/themes/parallel-pro/images/bg-demo2.jpg');
    }
    .stats {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .testimonials {
        background-color: #19232d;
    }
    #testimonials {
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .services .service i {
        color: #2b6560;
        font-size: 50px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .services .service i {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .services .service i {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .services .service h3 {
        line-height: 36px;
        letter-spacing: 1.25px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #19232d;
        font-size: 30px;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 0.24s ease-in-out;
    }
    .wf-loading .services .service h3 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .ie.wf-loading .services .service h3 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .services {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #services {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .pts {
        background-color: #f6f9fc;
    }
    .pts {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .brands {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #brands {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .calltoaction {
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url('https://frameless.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/widetm.jpg');
    }
    .calltoaction {
        padding-top: 150px;
        padding-bottom: 110px;
    }
    .calltoaction2 {
        background-color: #2b6560;
    }
    #calltoaction2 {
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .about {
        background-color: #ff3333;
    }
    #about {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .video {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-image: url('https://frameless.ca/wp-content/themes/parallel-pro/images/bg-demo4.jpg');
    }
    #team {
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .team {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #team {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .team {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #blog {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .newsletter {
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url('https://frameless.ca/wp-content/themes/parallel/images/bg-demo.jpg');
    }
    #newsletter {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .contact {
        background-color: #19232d;
    }
    #contact {
        padding-top: 66px;
        padding-bottom: 66px;
    }
    .copyright {
        background-color: #121a21;
    }
    #copyright {
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

If you see the above code closely, you will find that almost all the page sections and selectors are prefixed with `.wf-loading` class with either `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;` values.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about this cycle, I noticed it as well in the code. Unfortunately I cannot find the trace of what is causing these css codes. Is it possible to add a custom css to the end to disable all these loops?

Comment: Try this:

1. Login to WP Dashboard
2. Go to Appearance > Parallel Options > Custom Code
3. See the above code
4. Copy (just in case you need it later) and remove it
5. Click the Save Changes button
6. Check the site again

Comment: First of all, thank you kashif for responding to my questions and helping me out, i really appreciate it. Unfortunately i am not able to locate that code snippet above in the wordpress editor, it is not in the main style.css file, i am not sure where is code is, if its in the main html, i am not sure how to edit it. any pointers would greatly help, thank you!

Comment: Please follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334107/can-someone-explain-the-issue-that-is-happening-on-my-wordpress-theme-website/54335536?noredirect=1#comment95527544_54335536. I am pretty sure you will locate the said code.

Comment: *Unfortunately i am not able to locate that code snippet above in the wordpress editor, it is not in the main style.css file* - This code is not the part of the original theme, that’s why you are unable to locate it in style.css. This code is coming from the custom code section present in the theme option panel. I’ve listed step-by-step instruction in my earlier comment.